# How can I make an image fit into a circular box in span tag?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I need  to  make  it  into  the  circle  any help please ? thanxs in advance

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1"> 
    <span class="fa cherry-icon icon_1 i " style="font-size:40px;color:#ffffff;"> 
    <img width="154" height="154" src="<cms:show servic1_image/>" class="attachment-img-size-3 wp-post-image" /> 
</span> 
</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please add some code you have tried beforehand, this is not a "coders for free" service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `border-radius` property in CSS:

```css
.circle{
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.circle img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
<img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using **border-radius** property. I've added an example below.

```css
#circle{
  border-radius:50%;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:3px solid yellow;
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHUtK.jpg" id="circle">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-radius` in css

Example:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1459539235056-5045ca20e525?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=') center no-repeat;
}
.image-holder {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: calc(50vh - 75px);
}
.image-circle {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-holder">
    <img class="image-circle" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472461936147-645e2f311a2b?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```